# Is my motherboard failing?

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure

Last week, two separate SSDs failed (SMART errors I think it said) with no warning or hardware change. A couple days ago all of my USB ports stopped working after I plugged in my iPhone (the iPhone was not new, plugged it on many times before). The USB was down for a couple days and started working again a few minutes after I reattached in the old SSDs to run some diagnostics. I'm not sure if all these rents are connected but I am trying to be thorough in my description.

Is it possible that my motherboard is failing? It's an Asus X58 Extreme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recall exactly what the problem was but I am still using the same motherboard. One SSD definitely failed and was replaced. Not sure what happened with the USB but the problem is gone.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, no way to know for sure, but, it could be.

SSD and USB are not directly related and it is not common to have a problem with one that effects the other, with the exception of a critical component failing (chipset or power controllers).

The only thing I can say is to use the SSDs again and if you still can't use it, try on another PC and see what happens.

From what you said, it does seem like the machine could be failing, but, without isolating the errors and trying to use them on known good equipment (such as your phone on another pc), there isn't any way to know for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've been trying to isolate the best I can, but when multiple things start failing, even posting to SE can be problematic and frustrating (no usb => no mouse or keyboard)! The MB is the closest common denominator to the USB and SSD which is why I suspect it.